# How do I remove "tab borders" in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, border, jtabbedpane

I would like to remove the lines drawn around just the "tab" at the top. So I am on left with the label text.

How can I do this? I HAVE SEARCHED extensively but nothing works for me.

[image]

Comment: have you try  setBorder(null);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are all the UIManager values that seem to affect the area you are targeting.  As my previous answer didn't work for you I have listed all the ones I believe are relevant,  I would suggest copying the below list and then commenting various ones out to monitoring the effects and see if one, or a combination will prove successful for you.  I recommend putting them in before calling the tabbedpane constructor.

```
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.borderHightlightColor", java.awt.Color.CYAN); 
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.darkShadow", java.awt.Color.CYAN); 
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.light", java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selectHighlight", java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.darkShadow", java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", java.awt.Color.CYAN);
```

I have put the color CYAN because it is very bright, and so very clear what has changed with each one.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried all these colours: java.awt.Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, new Color(0, 0, 0,0) & null. But all leave a thin white border. The Color.GREEN actually puts a thin green border inside. So it almost is as if there are 2 borders...  None of them remove it though.

Comment: @ManInMoon I have re-jigged my answer with some more values, please try testing them on your application and see if you can get a correct combo.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TabbedPane.lightHighlight", Color.BLACK);
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TabbedPane.selectHighlight", Color.BLACK);
```

You might find something better in this list:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/JavaUIDefaults.txt